# Funded account, nothing showing up on testnet explorer

Tags: testnet

I have the following public address:

GAUXOMOELZVPX6RTKTZHR4MFGBMLHRKSGLBGBTXBW2J7AKCBG7E3OLP3

I tried funding the account in node js with

```
request('https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/friendbot?addr=GAUXOMOELZVPX6RTKTZHR4MFGBMLHRKSGLBGBTXBW2J7AKCBG7E3OLP3',function(err,res,body){
  console.log(body);
});
```

The body gave the default endpoint for the /friendbot without a tx hash.

Then, I tried to fund the same account with

https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/#account-creator?network=test

It said that it was successful, yet nothing shows up in the testnet explorer:

https://stellar.expert/explorer/testnet/account/GAUXOMOELZVPX6RTKTZHR4MFGBMLHRKSGLBGBTXBW2J7AKCBG7E3OLP3

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Friendbot intermittently failing to fund account](https://github.com/stellar/horizon/issues/427)

The issue persists. Yesterday it worked, but today not.

Until they close this issue, I think it's safer for you to use "Create Account" operation with their given set to set up your account.

> Step 1, Generate Keypair
>
> Step 2, "Create Account" with the following pair (<= 1000 lumen acceptable?)

```
Public Key    GBW74UVOXKGHO3WX6AV5ZGTB4JYBKCEJOUQAUSI25NRO3PKY5BC7WYZS
Secret Key    SA3W53XXG64ITFFIYQSBIJDG26LMXYRIMEVMNQMFAQJOYCZACCYBA34L
```

Comment: Thanks for the info - Just for my understanding of the network, do you know why the testbot sometimes doesn't work? I am planning to create an app that allows for automatic funding of new accounts and would prefer not to have something like this happen on the mainnet.

Comment: For years, friendbot was a function in Horizon. In a recent Horizon release (Jan/Feb 2018), they decided to separate this function to be a stand-alone application. https://github.com/stellar/go/releases

Comment: p.s. I have been running a private network to play with, and it is still running Horizon v0.11. I can say v0.11 is rather reliable up to now, and would not upgrade until I see it safe. https://github.com/stellar/horizon/releases